# Can you edit/modify the source code or yaml file in the google console for App engine apps already deployed

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to modify the already deployed app engine code and yaml file (need to reference nodejs10 or later) currently its nodejs8 which is depreciated.

I know you can easily create or modify cloud functions in the google cloud console, so is it possible for app engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With APp Engine, you can only [patch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services/patch) some part of the runtime configuration.

For the rest of the code, you have to know how the code is deployed on Google Cloud (it's the same things with cloud functions). The code isn't deployed like this, it is packaged in a container (thanks to Buildpack) and then deployed.

That's mean, you can't update this container, it is immutable. The Cloud Functions propose you a GUI to update your function (because a function is, normally, a small stuff, with few and small files), but when you save, you trigger a new container creation and deployment. It's not the previous version that you changed, you create a new version.

With App Engine, you have the capacity to view the source code in the debug mode

[image]

But you can't find download it (it's no longer possible, it was the case with app engine 1st gen, but not now).

If you haven't the code, you can copy it, file by file from the debugger and update it and redeploy it.

If you already have the code, change it and redeploy it. There is no other solution, especially when you change the runtime (BuildPack selects the base image of the container according to the runtime version).

Comment: Thx @guillaume that is what I thought, but i just wanted to make sure by getting someone else opinion. I guess ill have to redeploy, to just update the yaml file to upgrade from nodejs8 to nodejs10+